what orders to be triggered after a stock splits?
i saw this question but really didn't think it was answered properly. Meaning there was no yes or no answer. The original question was: Can I use limit orders to be triggered after a stock splits?
So when there is a stock going to split what order is used to buy it at the split price; of say $100.00?

Why do you care? The split doesn't change the value of your holdings. $1000 in stock before the split will be $1000 after the split and vice versa, just partitioned among a different number of shares. Splits are a convenience matter more than anything else; the big news (that the price became high enough to warrant a split) happened before the split.

Thanks for the explanation!  It helped for a straight "owned" stock split answer. The original question i believe was more to the point of making an order to buy the stock at the split price when the split happened. I would think like something akin to place an order for 110.00 to buy pre-split, executed the day of the split.  This question was not mine but not answered with such clarity as the split question 10-1 as you all did.  Thank you.

You'll need to check with your broker, but in the event of a split open orders will either be adjusted or cancelled.
Split on its own doesn't change the value of the position, so there's nothing to limit.

A dividend or a stock split doesn't change the value of your investment.
Open limit orders are adjusted to reflect the amount of the dividend or by the split ratio.  See FINRA rule 5330.
